# Passing SurfaceView to object constructors

Tags: android, static

Is it bad practice for a class to pass itself to its own objects?

For example:

```
public class MainView extends SurfaceView {
    Stack<GameObject> objs;

    public MainView() {
         new GameObject(this);
    }

    public void Add(GameObject obj) {
         objs.push(obj)
    }

    public void Remove(GameObject obj) {
         objs.pop(obj)
    }
}

public class GameObject {
    MainView parent;
    int state; 

    public GameObject(MainView parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
        parent.Add(this);
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        if(state == 1) {
              new GameObject(parent);
        } 
        else if(state == 2) {
              parent.Remove(this);
        } 
    }
}
```

I made an effort to remove static methods/variables. Now i have to pass the view to it's own objects. 
Is this a bad practice? 
Should objects have logic or should the SurfaceView contain all the logic?

Comment: Your question is not clear and from your provided code what is this line doing `new GameObject(this);` just creating the object and not using this.

Comment: Sorry, the code doesn't actually do anything. It's just for example. I just want to know if it's bad practice for a class to pass itself to its own objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you developing a game? If so I'd suggest you have a read [this](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?cat=22) and [this](http://www.edu4java.com/androidgame.html). The surfaceview should only have the job of rendering your game objects to the screen. Each game object however should hold the logic (its behavior) and a reference to a canvas to draw to which will eventually be drawn to the surfaceview. The overall logic of the game should however be in a class (eg. named world) that takes care of all the generating and managing of all the game objects.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Ah thank you! This site has alot of interesting code. My concern was if it was a bad practice to pass the SurfaceView into it's own objects. The example in your link does exactly that so I assume it's ok.